# Switching to Ubuntu from Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation

I want to switch to Ubuntu from Windows 8.1. I do not want to dual boot, just Ubuntu!

I have two disks C - system and D- which has my files and pictures.

I wonder if I can keep my D Disc while installing Ubuntu.
If I can, how?

Comment: I wonder why is this is Hot Network Questions list??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do keep the D: partition. Here's how it works:

- Select "Something Else" when being prompted to choose whether to remove Windows, to set up a dual boot or -  something else
- Remove your Windows partition (it's probably `/dev/sda1`, but check first)
- Create a new partition (preferrable EXT4)on the new empty space. Leave a empty area which as much space as you have RAM. (If you want SWAP)
- Set the mount point of the created partition to `/`. This will be the partition where Ubuntu will get installed.
- Create a new SWAP partition in the empty space as big as your RAM. (optional, but recommended)
- Make sure the device for bootloader installation (bottom) is the same as you where you created the partitions (should be `/dev/sda`)
- Click *Install now*

However, you should **always make a backup** of your files before installing new systems or formatting/partitioning a harddisk. Things can always go wrong.

And please notice that you won't be able to execute any scripts or programs from a NTFS partition, for it doesn't support Linux' file permissions.

Comment: Is "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" not the same (in this case)?

Comment: No. This would format your WHOLE harddisk. There's already a bug report for this, but with no effect yet.