# How to replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 in C drive without affecting other partitions

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

In my PC (2 GB RAM, 160 GB HDD) I have Windows 7 in Partition C  (20 GB). I have tried Ubuntu 12.04 from Live USB. I now want to replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 in the same C Partition *without affecting the other partitions and their contents*. I have read the answer to a similar question but still do not feel confident. Like in that question, I too have proceeded till "Something Else", but then precisely what steps should I take? Is it possible to simply choose the C Partition and start installing Ubuntu there? In that case what other choices should I make?

Comment: Look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/460495/265974 (replace D: with C:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After something else:

- Select Windows partition and click on "-"(which is beside the "+" icon).
- Now it shows it as an unknown partition. Click on "+" button. You'll get a window to manage that memory.
- Choose: "Primary partition", "Beginning of the memory space". Size as (8-9)GB. (1-2)GB is left now as free space.
- Select 1GB space and click on "+" icon and choose options like this: "Primary partition", "Beginning of the memory space", "swap area".
- Click install.
- Comment.

Comment: Can I ask some more information? There is also a small partition named "dev/sda1 Windows 7 (loader)" of 100 MB size -- should I delete that as well? Secondly, what do I choose for "Device for bootloader installation"? Is it dev/sda, i.e. the whole 160 GB HDD? Or is it the newly created partition where Ubuntu is going to be installed?

Comment: 1. YOU SHOULD NOT DELETE 100 MB PARTITION. 2. BOOT LOADER IS WHOLE HDD i.e. DEV/SDA. 3. EVERYTHING SHOULD BE FINE...

Comment: You mean I shouldn't delete the 100 MB Windows loader partition even though I am completely removing Windows?? Thanks for the Bootloader information.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't read the question clearly. If you're completely removing Windows you can delete that partition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a bootable USB of Ubuntu ISO file.
(Make sure your important files are not in Windows 7 partition)

Restart your PC and boot up your USB.
While installing, select "Replace Ubuntu with Windows 7"

That's it!

Comment: No, I am afraid that's not the way, for it will erase all other partitions with their contents!